# Как использовать комбинацию alt + space в vscode?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Комбинация клавиш биндится без проблем, но при нажатии вылазит контекстное меню окна программы vscode. Есть ли способ отключить эту windows комбинацию, при этом оставив ее работоспособной для программ?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя. Это встроено в винду.(даже калькулятор для нее критично важен)
Можешь помучиться в реестре, но не думаю, что кто-то уже это там менял хоть раз.

Comment: Прост, sublime text нормально дружит с этой комбинацией. Думал, может и vscode удастся подружить.

Comment: Хз тогда, мб сублайм не сделана майкрософт, которых тяжело обойти, но при этом они сами себя периодически обходят

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).